# Combine array values to a clickable link

Tags: php, arrays, hyperlink

Hi everyone i got a problem. I made a wishlist which outputs the result as array with the selected value her an example

```
Array ( [product_name] => 1 [Testartikel 1] => 2 [Testartikel 4] => 5)
```

its not the right output how can i put out the values like this

```
<a href="1">product_name</a> <a href="2">Testartikel 1</a> <a href="5">Testartikel 4</a>
```

my output for the array is this one actuallay

```
<?php
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION['orders']);
?>
```

and items are generated in wlscript.php file which looks like this

```
<?php
session_start();
if (is_array($_SESSION['orders']))
{
$orders = $_SESSION['orders'];
}
$p = trim($_POST['wlproduct']);
$q = trim($_POST['wlproducturl']);
$orders[$p] = $q;
$_SESSION['orders'] = $orders;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make from your session array the output with links, you can use this code:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['orders'] as $row => $link) {
    echo '<a href="' . $link . '">' . $row . '</a>';
}
```

Output will be three links in format you write.